# How many different DFS's and BFS's can we make out of a graph ? do DFS's show more variety or BFS 's?

Tags: graph, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

i'm tryna to find it out how many different BFS and DFS trees can i construct out of a given graph if this is impossible to determine exactly then i wanna to know if the DFS's has more variety than BFS's sure all of them related to the given graph !

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the complexities answer your question

***Depth-first search***

**Worst case performance**   O(|E|)  for explicit graphs traversed without repetition,  **O(b^{d})**  for implicit graphs with branching factor b searched to depth d.

**Worst case space complexity** O(|V|) if entire graph is traversed without repetition, **O(longest path length searched)** for implicit graphs without elimination of duplicate nodes

&

***Breadth-first search***

**Worst case performance**   O(|E|)=O(b^{d})

**Worst case space complexity**  O(|V|)=O(b^{d})